# Fix for Keeping Data Organized Correctly Without Repeating

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, text-files, insertion-sort

I've been working with data from a file and keeping them paired together. I need to sort the data alphabetically while keeping them paired together at the same time. Here is my text file:

```
Joe
Jake
Toronto
32
joejake@gmail.com
Bob
Barley
Vancouver
13
bobbarley@gmail.com
Felix
Fixed
Boston
24
felixfixed@gmail.com
```

This is what I need the output to be:

```
First Name:
Bob
Last Name:
Barley
City:
Vancouver
Age:
13
Email:
bobbarley@gmail.com
First Name:
Felix
Last Name:
Fixed
City:
Boston
Age:
24
Email:
felixfixed@gmail.com
First Name:
Joe
Last Name:
Jake
City:
Toronto
Age:
32
Email:
joejake@gmail.com
```

Ideally, when I sort them, the first and last name, etc. would be paired together correctly. However, what I currently have results in this output:

```
First Name:
Bob
Last Name:
Barley
City:
Vancouver
Age:
13
Email:
bobbarley@gmail.com
First Name:
Felix
Last Name:
Fixed
City:
Boston
Age:
24
Email:
felixfixed@gmail.com
First Name:
Joe
Last Name:
Fixed
City:
Boston
Age:
24
Email:
felixfixed@gmail.com
```

Here is the code that I wrote:

```
public static void insertfname (String fname [], String lname [], String city [], String age [], String email []) throws IOException
{
    int howMany = 0;
    int count = count (howMany);

    for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
    {
        String current = fname [i];
        String current2 = lname [i];
        String current3 = city [i];
        String current4 = age [i];
        String current5 = email [i];
        int j = i - 1;
        //Insertion sort and keeping records together
        while (j >= 0 && current.compareToIgnoreCase (fname [j]) < 0)
        {
            fname [j + 1] = fname [j];
            j--;
        }
        fname [j + 1] = current;

        while (j >= 0 && current.compareToIgnoreCase (fname [j]) < 0)
        {
            lname [j + 1] = lname [j];
            j--;
        }
        lname [j + 1] = current2;

        while (j >= 0 && current.compareToIgnoreCase (fname [j]) < 0)
        {
            city [j + 1] = city [j];
            j--;
        }
        city [j + 1] = current3;

        while (j >= 0 && current.compareToIgnoreCase (fname [j]) < 0)
        {
            age [j + 1] = age [j];
            j--;
        }
        age [j + 1] = current4;

        while (j >= 0 && current.compareToIgnoreCase (fname [j]) < 0)
        {
            email [j + 1] = email [j];
            j--;
        }
        email [j + 1] = current5;
    }
}
```

Comment: Java is Object Oriented, meaning you can combine multiple related data variables into a single overarching class. I'd strongly suggest you use classes here as it would be far easier to make sure your data is grouped properly than using parallel arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Mihir Kekkar is right, this is just an example;

Define the contact class,

`class ContactData implements Comparable<ContactData>`

Override compareTo method for sort

`public int compareTo(ContactData other)`

Make the contact array and sort it with

`Arrays.sort(yourOwnContactArray);`

This uses the overridden compareTo method.  While you have a default sort method, still you can use other methods for sort like;

`List<ContactData> listContacts = make-your-own ...`

then use Collections.sort with other/different Comparator

```
`Collections.sort(listContacts, (a,b) -> {
   return a.lastName.concat(a.name).compareTo(b.lastName.concat(b.name));
 });`
```